# What do we know about the seven nations in Deut. 7:1, 2?

Tags: history, deuteronomy

In Deut 7:1, 2 we read of seven nations that were cast out. What were they known for in terms if their religion or culture, that merited their total annihilation?
Why were they so bad that they needed to be completely wiped out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character of Canaanite inhabitants can be partially judged by the incident recorded earlier in Gen 19 which also required extermination.  This sort of effect of idol worship of false gods is alluded to often in the OT.

- Lev 18:27 - For the men who were in the land before you committed all these **abominations**, and the land has become defiled. [These abominations are listed earlier in Lev 18 - disgusting sexual practices.]
- Deut 29:17 - You saw the **abominations** and idols among them made of wood and stone, of silver and gold.
- 2 Kings 21:11, 12 - Since Manasseh king of Judah has committed all these **abominations**, acting more wickedly than the **Amorites** who preceded him, and with his idols has caused Judah to sin, this is what the LORD, the God of Israel, says: ‘Behold, I am bringing such calamity upon Jerusalem and Judah that the news will reverberate in the ears of all who hear it.
- 2 Kings 17:15 - They rejected His statutes and the covenant He had made with their fathers, as well as the decrees He had given them. They pursued **worthless idols and themselves became worthless**, going after the surrounding nations that the LORD had commanded them not to imitate.
- Jer 2:5 - This is what the LORD says: “What fault did your fathers find in Me that they strayed so far from Me, and followed **worthless idols, and became worthless themselves**?
- Eze 14:6 - “Therefore say to the house of Israel, Thus says the Lord GOD: Repent and turn away from your idols, and turn away your faces from all your **abominations**.
- Eze 6:9 - Then in the nations to which they have been carried captive, your survivors will remember Me—how I have been grieved by their adulterous hearts that turned away from Me, and by their eyes that **lusted after idols**. So they will loathe themselves for the evil they have done and for all their **abominations**.
- Eze 22;11 - One man commits an **abomination** with his neighbor’s wife; another wickedly defiles his daughter-in-law; and yet another violates his sister, his own father’s daughter.

These "abominable" practices included things like abhorrent sexual practices (Lev 18), child sacrifice, the normalization of extreme violence, absence of civil justice, etc.  [There is a modern counterpart to this sort of thing seen in the beheading by children of "unbelievers" in the Levant over the last 10 years.]  All these things degraded the people so much as to put them beyond the reach of even God.

**APPENDIX - The Seven Nations of Deut 7:1.**

Here is an extract from the Cambridge commentary on Deut 7:1 concerning the seven nations.

> **Hittite** Egyptian and Assyrian monuments record a Ḥittite power in N. Syria with a centre at Ḳadesh on the Orontes. Jdg 1:26; Jdg 3:23,
> Joshua 11:3 (in these last two read Ḥittite for Ḥivite) bring the name
> as far as the S. end of Mt Hermon. P mentions people of the same or a
> similar name in S. Palestine as owning the land about Ḥebron (Genesis
> 23:3; Genesis 23:10), and gives Esau wives of the daughters of Ḥeth
> (Genesis 26:4; Genesis 27:46). Ezekiel (Ezekiel 16:3, cp. Ezekiel
> 16:45) calls the mother of Jerusalem a Ḥittite. On these grounds (and
> others) the existence of at least Ḥittite colonies or suzerainties in
> S. Palestine has been maintained. But in P Ḥittite may be used in the
> same general sense as Amorite in E and D and Canaanite in J; cp.
> Joshua 1:4 (deuteronomic) all the land of the Ḥ. = all Syria, which
> the Assyrians also mean by ‘the land of the Khatti’; and P’s Ḥittites
> at Hebron are called Amorites by E, Joshua 10:5; while Ezekiel, too,
> may have no ethnological distinction in mind, but may mean only to
> emphasise the inborn heathenism of Jerusalem. The question is still
> uncertain and of no importance for the understanding of a rhetorical
> list like this. For details see the writer’s Jerus. II. 16–18.
>
> **Girgashite** in but a few of the lists; here, Joshua 3:10; Joshua 24:11; Genesis 15:21. Genesis 10:16 (J) puts them under the political
> supremacy of Canaan (begotten by C.) or Phoenicia. Their territory is
> unknown. The name seems onomatopoetic like Zamzummim (Deuteronomy
> 2:20); cp. Arab, ‘garas,’ to make a low sound or speak softly.
>
> **Amorite** … Canaanite] See on Deuteronomy 1:7. [See below]
>
> **Perizzite** in all but two or three of the lists. J mentions this people, along with the Canaanite, as Israel’s predecessors (Genesis
> 13:7; Genesis 34:30; Jdg 1:4-5), and their land as in the centre of
> the range of W. Palestine (Joshua 17:15). The name has been derived,
> but not certainly, from perazah, ‘open region’ or ‘region of unwalled
> towns,’ perazi, ‘the inhabitant of such’ (Deuteronomy 3:5).
>
> **Hivite** in all the lists. In J they are subject to Phoenicia (Canaan, Genesis 10:17) and the Gibeonites are called Ḥivites (Joshua
> 9:7; cp. the deuteronomic Deuteronomy 11:19). In 2 Samuel 24:7 their
> cities are coupled with those of the Canaanites as now Israel’s. The
> Heb. Ḥiwwi seems connected with ḥawwah, tent-village.
>
> **Jebusite** in all the lists save one; according to J and other sources the inhabitants of Jerusalem and its land till their conquest
> by David (Joshua 15:63; Jdg 1:21; Jdg 19:11; 2 Samuel 5:6; 2 Samuel
> 5:8); cf. P’s the shoulder of the Jebusite, that is Jerusalem, Joshua
> 18:16; Joshua 18:28. See the writer’s Jerus. i. 226 f., ii. 18, 28.

Here is another extract from the same source on Deut 1:7

> **Amorite**, in D as in E, is the general name for all the tribes dispossessed by Israel; J has Canaanite. Winckler explains this from
> the origin of E in N. Israel where the Amorites had been in force;
> while J, writing in Judah where Israel had not fought the Amorites,
> knew nothing of them but assigned the whole land to the Canaanites,
> whose civilisation had been paramount on the coast at the time of
> Israel’s entry and who continued to form an antithesis to Israel
> (Gesch. Isr. i. 53). If this argument were sound, then D’s extension
> of the name Amorite to the S. of W. Palestine would be artificial. But
> Winckler himself recognises the ancient character of the tradition
> which calls Sîḥôn an Amorite (op. cit. p. 52), and if the Amorites had
> penetrated to Moab, they had also, it is probable, extended their
> sovereignty as far S. on the W. of the Jordan.